# Duplicate objects not showing up in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

My duplicated objects are not showing up in the render. Visibility is on and Show In Renders is checked. I feel like I've tried everything. What am I missing?

I'm using cycles.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the file you share you have keyframed your object, it has a location that is not the one you show, if you want to make sure that this object stays at the good position you need to keyframe it again, is it your problem here?

Comment: That was it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file you share you have keyframed your object, it has a location that is not the one you show, if you want to make sure that this object stays at the good position you need to keyframe it again?